# How to rename sudoers back to its original naming?

Tags: sudo

Today I made a big mistake, I run  the command

```
mv /etc/sudoers{,.bak}
```

on my ubuntu machine and now sudoers file is missing

This is the message given in terminal wherever I use sudo

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

How to make that backup file again back to normal and get back `sudo`?

Comment: If you search for the name of the backup file are you able to locate it anywhere on your filesystem?

Comment: does `mv /etc/sudoers{.bak,}` work?

Comment: @fedorqui no it says `permission denied`

Comment: @ParanoidPanda yes I can locate it in my file system

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the fastest way to fix this would be to get a root shell from the recovery mode and to move the original `/etc/sudoers` back in place:

1. Hold <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd> (or <kbd>ESC</kbd> if <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd> doesn't work) at power-on to boot into `grub`;
2. Select the default kernel's recovery mode (e.g. `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (recovery mode)`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
3. Select `root - Drop to root shell prompt` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
4. Run `mount -o rw,remount /`;
5. Run `mv /etc/sudoers.bak /etc/sudoers`;
6. Run `reboot`;

Comment: Thanks for very detailed help!!!!... now my day will go all right!!!

Comment: @SurajPalwe No problem :)

Answer (score 11):

Oh I've done this one before. :) oops...

1. Reboot using a LIVE CD (The one you installed Ubuntu with)
2. Choose the "Try Ubuntu" option NOT the "Install Ubuntu" option.

   Once you are to the desktop just mount your main HDD (should show at the bottom left as a hard drive)
3. Launch the file manager and navigate to the `/etc/` folder on that newly mounted hard drive.
4. Rename the `sudoers.bak` file to `sudoers`.

Reboot and you should be good to go. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This is fine, +1, however getting a root shell from `grub` should be faster / easier

Comment: I'm not to familiar with how to manipulate grub but I figured if he does not know how to fix the renaming of a file he's never going to figure out how to mount his drive via shell to get access to the contents to fix the issue.

Comment: That's probably right, however nevermind, I just added another answer myself (with step-by-step instructions)

Comment: This is also accepted answer but I tried using @kos answer , as I didn't had CD with me right now.. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 11):

Since Ubuntu also has `pkexec` installed, and Polkit configuration is independent of `sudoers`:

```
pkexec mv /etc/sudoers{.bak,}
```

Comment: Ah not that a +19 on an answer like the one I gave were deserved, but to see that it's not even the best answer also feels a bit uncomfortable. @SurajPalwe I think this should be the accepted answer, it's way better than my answer.

Comment: @kos thanks, but the command was correct as is. I was using brace expansion.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Pardon me.

Comment: +1 It never ceases to amaze me how often I find important things like this that I have never seen before! This comes under the heading of "elegant".